# $.post de JQuery no me envia datos a php

Tags: php, javascript

tengo una duda al enviar datos desde una funcion en JS usando $.post de JQuery, ya que al enviar los datos no ingresa al php siempre lo echo aunque con java esta vez en php pero no funciona me da el error en la consola el siguiente

```
ReferenceError: $ is not definedscript.js:5:5
enviar http://localhost/Talleranimales/js/script.js:5
onclick http://localhost/Talleranimales/index.php:1
```

La linea 1 del html es `<!DOCTYPE html>` y la linea 5 del js es la del `$.post('recibe.php`

mi html

```
 <input type="text" id="txt">
        <button type="button" onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button>
```

js

```
function enviar() {
    nombre = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    console.log(nombre);

    $.post('recibe.php', { opcion: nombre }, function(rs) {
        console.log(rs);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta agregar la libreria `jQuery` o la estas cargando después de tu script principal:

```
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src = "mainScript.js"></script>  <!--Tu script principal-->
```

Answer (score 0):

efectivamente falta agregar la librería JQUERY

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="txt">
        <button type="button" onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button>

        <script
                      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
                      integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
                      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script>
      function enviar() {
          nombre = document.getElementById('txt').value;
          console.log(nombre);

          $.post('recibe.php', { opcion: nombre }, function(rs) {
              console.log(rs);
          });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```